# How do I Reverse Display a Linked List?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a function that inserts random integers into a list, and a function that displays the list. With what i have now, is there a way to display that list in reverse?

```
   void InsertRandomInts() 
{
LinkedSortedList<int> list;
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) 
{
    int b = rand() % 100 + 1;
    list.insertSorted(b);
}       
displayListForward(&list);

}


void displayListForward(SortedListInterface<int>* listPtr)
{
cout << "The sorted list contains " << endl;
for (int pos = 1; pos <= listPtr->getLength(); pos++)
{
    cout << listPtr->getEntry(pos) << " ";
}
cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good idea would be to get rid of that non-standard generic container and instead use `std::list` (or really just `std::vector` if you don't need list-specific semantics such as being able to remove an element without invaliding iterators to other elements).

The `sort` member function can be applied after all items have been added. You can then finally use `rbegin` and `rend` for reverse iteration.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void DisplayListForward(std::list<int>& list)
{
    std::cout << "The sorted list contains\n";

    for (auto iter = list.rbegin(); iter != list.rend(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void InsertRandomInts() 
{
    std::list<int> list;
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(nullptr)));

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) 
    {
        auto const b = std::rand() % 100 + 1;
        list.push_back(b);
    }

    list.sort();

    DisplayListForward(list);
}

int main()
{
    InsertRandomInts();
}
```

But this may be overkill; for a quick solution, just reverse your current loop:

```
for (int pos = listPtr->getLength(); pos >= 1; pos--)
```

Comment: For what I need to do, I'll take the quick solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the list from `rbegin()` to `rend()` and print it. You will be printing it in reverse.

Either 1) stop reinventing the wheel and just use a standard container that has these functions.  Or 2) implement rbegin() & rend() for your custom container.

Like

```
for (auto it = list.rbegin(); it != it.rend(); ++it)
    // Print *it
```

Comment: how would that look in code? That sounds like exactly what Im doing with print forward.

Comment: @Christian Hackl then OP could either 1) stop reinventing the wheel and just use a standard container. Or 2) implement `rbegin()` & `rend()` for his custom container.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: This should not be a comment but the introduction of your answer.

Comment: where are you getting auto from. I was using int. And if the length of my list is say 50, could i replace rend() with 50?

Comment: @Kenneth Dionisi [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

Comment: what would the function declaration look like, would it be like void displayListBackwards(SortedListInterface<auto>listPtr)?

Comment: @KennethDionisi: No, `auto` cannot be used like that. However, getting rid of the pointer argument is something you should do regardless of the solution you choose. You don't use pointers for those things in C++, you use references instead: `displayListBackwards(SortedListInterface<int>& list)`